# I am trying to make a calculator but i keep getting the error (C3861 'add': identifier not found)

Tags: visual-c++

I am in class trying to figure out how to program this calculator in c++, and it is giving me the error code C3861. I have no idea why my program isn't working the way  it's supposed to.

the code related to the error is right here

```
answer = add(x, y);
```

the function add calls is this

```
    int add(int x, int y)
{
    int answer = 0;

    answer = x + y;

    return answer;
}
```

the line is supposed to call a function called add that's supposed to add x and y but I don't have a clue why it won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the function before you can use it.

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
    int answer = 0;

    answer = x + y;

    return answer;
}
int main()
{
   int x,y, answer;
   answer = add(x, y);
}
```

will work or you can define the prototype of the function and then define it.

```
int add(int x, int y);    
int main()
{
   int x,y, answer;
   answer = add(x, y);
}
int add(int x, int y)
{
    int answer = 0;

    answer = x + y;

    return answer;
}
```

Maybe you should start with a tutorial. [Tuto c++](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/19-header-files/)